# Using "then" at the end of a response

Tags: grammaticality

With no prior conversation, person A says to person B: "Your mother would've been very proud of you."
Person B then says: "You didn't know my mother very well then."

Does "then" work here? 
It doesn't seem right.

This is a video of the interaction I'm talking about (Between two video game characters)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqIKRL_5f6o&feature=youtu.be&t=90

Comment: duplicate: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6868/then-at-the-end-of-a-sentence

Comment: It's correct.  It'd be no different than if Person B had said, "Then you didn't know my mother very well."  The "then" is implying a conditional clause (i.e. "If you say so, then you didn't know my mother very well.").  In back and forth dialogue or conversation, we often build directly off what the prior person said, incorporating what they said like it is part and parcel of what we are saying, which sometimes makes what we say, our responses, sound like a fragment.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman But is it correct to say "build off" something? Based off of the stuff I've been reading on the internet, I guess "off" has become a synonym for "on".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my mind it's not *quite* "fully okay". Perhaps for the same reason OP says it doesn't seem right.

I think ordinarily when a speaker ends (or starts) his response with *then* (or *therefore, in that case,* etc.), it's a kind of [discourse marker](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/discourse-markers-so-right-okay) meaning something like Samuel Johnson's [*I refute it **thus**!*](http://www.samueljohnson.com/refutati.html) (kicking out at a stone, a relatively aggressive illustration of his point).

So it *could* seem misplaced in OP's cited context because of the implied rejection/refutation of a hostile remark or false claim. Which simply doesn't fit well when A has just offered "vicarious" praise that B is bashfully/ruefully admitting he can't accept (because he knows his mother wouldn't have given it in the first place).

There's also that point about *with no prior conversation*. These discourse markers are quite strongly associated with repeated "tit-for-tat" taunt/counter-taunt exchanges, but they're not usually used in either side's *first* contribution. I understand *then* as referring back to the other party's *most recent* verbal attack (but not the first one; that's just like returning the service in tennis, not really part of the rally that might follow).

Which is not to say the usage is "wrong". I'm just explaining why ***I*** think it's "less-than-perfect".